# Deploying a PHP Library project with Maven

Tags: php, maven-2, deployment, repository

I've created a PHP Library project using Maven, and I'm now ready for its deployment. Following the instructions at http://www.php-maven.org/deploy.html, something went wrong.
The configuration is set to:

```
<descriptorRef>php-lib</descriptorRef>
```

During the execution of `mvn deploy` I get a list of errors for unfound dependencies in the repository:

```
[INFO] [jar:jar {execution: default-jar}]
[INFO] Building jar: /home/marco/projects/php/my-app/target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] [plugin:addPluginArtifactMetadata {execution: default-addPluginArtifactMetadata}]
Downloading: http://repo1.php-maven.org/release/org/phpmaven/maven-php-plugin/2.2-beta-2/maven-php-plugin-2.2-beta-2.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.phpmaven:maven-php-plugin:pom:2.2-beta-2' in repository release-repo1.php-maven.org (http://repo1.php-maven.org/release)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/phpmaven/maven-php-plugin/2.2-beta-2/maven-php-plugin-2.2-beta-2.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.phpmaven:maven-php-plugin:pom:2.2-beta-2' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
Downloading: http://repo1.php-maven.org/release/org/phpmaven/maven-php-plugin/2.2-beta-2/maven-php-plugin-2.2-beta-2.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.phpmaven:maven-php-plugin:pom:2.2-beta-2' in repository release-repo1.php-maven.org (http://repo1.php-maven.org/release)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/phpmaven/maven-php-plugin/2.2-beta-2/maven-php-plugin-2.2-beta-2.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.phpmaven:maven-php-plugin:pom:2.2-beta-2' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
Downloading: http://repo1.php-maven.org/release/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http-shared/1.0-beta-6/wagon-http-shared-1.0-beta-6.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-shared:pom:1.0-beta-6' in repository release-repo1.php-maven.org (http://repo1.php-maven.org/release)
Downloading: http://repo1.php-maven.org/release/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http-shared/1.0-beta-6/wagon-http-shared-1.0-beta-6.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-shared:pom:1.0-beta-6' in repository release-repo1.php-maven.org (http://repo1.php-maven.org/release)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http-shared/1.0-beta-6/wagon-http-shared-1.0-beta-6.pom

Downloading: http://repo1.php-maven.org/release/nekohtml/xercesMinimal/1.9.6.2/xercesMinimal-1.9.6.2.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'nekohtml:xercesMinimal:pom:1.9.6.2' in repository release-repo1.php-maven.org (http://repo1.php-maven.org/release)
Downloading: http://repo1.php-maven.org/release/nekohtml/xercesMinimal/1.9.6.2/xercesMinimal-1.9.6.2.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'nekohtml:xercesMinimal:pom:1.9.6.2' in repository release-repo1.php-maven.org (http://repo1.php-maven.org/release)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/nekohtml/xercesMinimal/1.9.6.2/xercesMinimal-1.9.6.2.pom
```

And this is my settings.xml file:

```
<settings>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>profile-php-maven</id>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>release-repo1.php-maven.org</id>
                    <name>PHP-Maven 2 Release Repository</name>
                    <url>http://repo1.php-maven.org/release</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                </pluginRepository>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>snapshot-repo1.php-maven.org</id>
                    <name>PHP-Maven 2 Snapshot Repository</name>
                    <url>http://repo1.php-maven.org/snapshot</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>release-repo1.php-maven.org</id>
                    <name>PHP-Maven 2 Release Repository</name>
                    <url>http://repo1.php-maven.org/release</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>snapshot-repo1.php-maven.org</id>
                    <name>PHP-Maven 2 Snapshot Repository</name>
                    <url>http://repo1.php-maven.org/snapshot</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>profile-php-maven</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

For every step I've followed the documentation (which is poor, though).

Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see this file: http://repo1.php-maven.org/release/org/phpmaven/maven-php-plugin/2.2-beta-2/maven-php-plugin-2.2-beta-2.pom but I do see: http://repo1.php-maven.org/release/org/phpmaven/maven-php-plugin/1.1/maven-php-plugin-1.1.pom might want to update it to the correct pom file

Answer (score 0):

Following the instructions here: http://www.php-maven.org/deploy.html you need to edit the  tag(s) to use this pom: http://repo1.php-maven.org/release/org/phpmaven/maven-php-plugin/1.1/maven-php-plugin-1.1.pom

Looks like `<version>2.2-beta-2</version>` is not available.